# Swift & Firebase Cannot assign value of type 'AuthDataResult?' to type 'User?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am revisiting an old app but before I work on new features I want to fix all errors. I'm not sure if this is caused by newer Swift syntax or updates to Firebase (or both) but code which previously worked is now causing 2 errors.

```
var user = Auth.auth().currentUser


Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: theEmail, password: thePassword, completion: { (user, error) in
  if let theError = error {

    var errMessage = "An unknown error occured."
    if let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: (theError._code)) {
      switch errCode {

      case .invalidEmail:
        errMessage = "The entered email does not meet requirements."
      case .emailAlreadyInUse:
        errMessage = "The entered email has already been registered."
      case .weakPassword:
        errMessage = "The entered password does not meet minimum requirements."
      default:
        errMessage = "Please try again."
      }
    }
    completion(nil, errMessage)
  } else {
    self.user = user
    completion(user, nil)
  }
})
```

On `self.user = user` the error message is `Cannot assign value of type 'AuthDataResult?' to type 'User?'`

On `completion(user, nil)` the error message is `Cannot convert value of type 'AuthDataResult?' to expected argument type 'User?'`

Could somebody explain why this code which once worked no longer works and what I can do to bring it up to current expectations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
self.user = user
```

with

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: theEmail, password: thePassword, completion: { (authData, error) in

    .....

    if let res = authData?.user {
      self.user = res
    }

}
```